# IOS5 -[__NSCFDictionary nombre]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6da25a0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, instance

I get an error when trying to access an attribute of a class "event"

Json List all Ok When I trying to access the error jumps

```
Evento* bean = [ListaEventos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
DetalleViewController *detalle = [self.storyboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detalle"];
NSLog(@"detalle: %@",[bean nombre]);//bean Log OK!!, but bean.nombre Error!! why?
```

The class: evento.h

```
@interface Evento : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSString *idevento;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSString *nombre;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSString *descripcion;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSString *fecha;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSString *telefono;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSString *direccion;

@end
```

Evento.m

```
@implementation Evento

@synthesize idevento;
@synthesize nombre;
@synthesize descripcion;
@synthesize fecha;
@synthesize telefono;
@synthesize direccion;

@end
```

Comment: Obviously, `bean` is an `NSDictionary`, not an instance of `Evento`. Most likely, you need to enable NSZombies and look for an over-release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get out of `[ListaEventos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` is of kind `NSDictionary` and not of kind `Evento` as supposed. Check your data!

Comment: And check the objective-c variable naming conventions too by the way.

Comment: Thank you, was a rookie mistake instead of saving the object kept the dictionario not appropriate naming = error ... thanks and sorry for the dumb question xD

Comment: You're welcome, we've all been there! If your problem is solved now, please close the question by accepting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The object you get with

```
[ListaEventos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Is of type dictionary which doesn't have the method or the property nombre.
If you could add also add here the json we can help you to get the correct evento object.